# Sorting A Json Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

After losing the lotto tonight I decided I was going to try and see if picking the most common numbers people win with gets me more numbers hit in future games.

So I wrote a `js` function to run through a multi dimensional array and count the number of occurrences each number appears. This way in the future I can add to the array and see what the top 6 most picked numbers are each week. 
 "I realize I am not going to win the lottery like this, I'm a nerd and this is how I enjoy myself."

At this point I have an `object` literal and read that it is best to convert to `json` before sorting because it is not accurate.

So I used,

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

My program shows me the each number in my multidimensional array and then shows me how many times it has been mentioned.

At this point my json output looks like this,

```
{"1":6,"2":6,"3":6,"4":6,"5":5,"6":6,"7":1}
```

All of the examples I see to sort json have json that looks like this,

```
        "zip": "00010",
        "price": "962500"
```

With something like that I could do this to sort by price,

```
numbersCalced.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.price - b.price;
});
```

But in my case my goal is to show the top 6 largest numbers. So I can't just sort by any number between 1 and 49. How can I sort this json not by the number but by the amount it occurred.

At that point it will be easy to move the top 6 numbers to an output.

```
{"1":6,"2":6,"3":6,"4":6,"5":5,"6":6,"7":1}
```

Here is the full script if it helps,

```js
    var arr = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ];
    // 49 numbers is the real game
    
    var obj = {};
    
    for (var g = 0; g < arr.length; g++) {
        for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (obj[arr[g][i]]) {
                obj[arr[g][i]]++;
            } else {
                obj[arr[g][i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    var numbersCalced = JSON.stringify(obj)
    
    
    console.log(numbersCalced);
```

**TO BE CLEAR** it is sorting it as of now. Putting it in order of the number not the occurrence.

so 1 occurrences 7 will always be in the 0 place. How can I show the order based on the occurrences?

Comment: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) doesn't sort anything ;)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not sorting with json.stringify I am changing a object literal to json.  and the question is repeated in the last sentence of the question if you did not read the whole thing.